# 'Any' is not convertible to '[[String : Any]]'

Tags: swift3, nsjsonserialization

How can I cast `Any` type I'm getting from `JSONSerialization` to an array of dictionaries? My code is:

```
    let jsonArray: [[AnyHashable: Any]]

    do {

        jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [.ReadingOptions.allowFragments]) as! [[AnyHashable : Any]]
    }
    catch {
        let description = NSLocalizedString("Could not analyze earthquake data", comment: "Failed to unpack JSON")
        print(description)
        return
    }
```

But compiler gives me error message:

> 'Any' is not convertible to '[[AnyHashable : Any]]'

P.S.

I need to parse array of dictionaries, so JSON file looks like this:

```
[{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "123"
}, {
  "username": "bbvb",
  "password": "3333"
}, {
  "username": "asd",
  "password": "222"
}]
```

Comment: Don't use  force casting, since the JSON data might be corrupted or incorrect, use optional casting with the `as?` operator. Also, according to the JSON specification, the JSON keys must be `String`s, so there's no reason to use `AnyHashable` as your dictionaries keys. However, without seeing your actual `JSON` response we can't give exact help, most probably you are not receiving a expected JSON format.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I updated post with JSOn example. Changing 'AnyHashable' to 'String' is not fixing anything. If data will be corrupted, 'do catch' will catch it, so no need to use optionals.

Comment: That is not true. The do-catch block only catches throwable errors, but the force casting can't be caught. The do-catch block only catches the error if the data cannot be decoded into JSON, but it being JSON doesn't mean that it will be in the correct format as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks, will rewrite it.

Comment: Moreover, the catch block in `Swift` provides a built-in error variable, you should print that along your own error message. Is that JSON extract actually printed from inside your app? You should try removing the casting altogether for debugging purposes and printing the `Any` JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using `AnyHashable` ??

Try this:

```
    let jsonArray: Any? = nil

    do {



jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [Any] 

        if jsonArray != nil {
          if let resp = jsonArray as? [[AnyHashable : Any]]{

         //your result should be here inside resp, which is an array of dictionary of key-val type `AnyHashable : Any`, although you could just use String value for the key, making your format from  [[AnyHashable : Any]] to [[String : Any]]
        }

   }
   catch {
            let description = NSLocalizedString("Could not analyze earthquake data", comment: "Failed to unpack JSON")
            print(description)
            return
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with 'AnyHashable'? Why I can't use it?

Comment: You can use AnyHashable but it depends on the structure of your JSON, if your key is of type nested structure.

Comment: I was using your code in Xcode, got many error messages. I don't have a JSON file yet.

Comment: You can use AnyHashable but should do so ideally when you have your dictionary keys in a kind of nested structure, or when you are not sure of the type value residing in keys... in case you just have String as keys it can be avoided as it will save you an extra check which is required while using AnyHashable key.

Comment: According to your updated json you should use type [[String:Any]] i.e. jsonArray as? [[String:Any]]

Comment: It totally works to convert 'Any' to a dictionary, but not into an array of dictionaries, for some reason.

Comment: for array of dictionaries it could be a two step process... first get array of Any like as? [Any], then in the next step parse that array's individual object as dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151643/discussion-between-umar-farooque-and-shmidt).

Comment: @Shmidt great please accept the answer if it helped